# Does the Firebase Unity SDK work with desktop?

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase

Does the Firebase Unity SDK work with PC and Mac? They seem to say they only support mobile, but I need a cloud provider like Parse to use with Unity that supports Desktop (as well as mobile).

Comment: Great question.  Say, did you ever try back4app.com?  it seems to be a parse clone.

Comment: Joe Blow I want a more stable service like AWS or Firebase, Parse is deprecated. Also, Parse's Unity SDK was for mobile only.

Comment: consider Gamesparks??  they're getting bigger all the time and specialize in games

Comment: I'm actually doing a non-game app with Unity3D

Comment: gotchya.  I'm sure you know, AWS is basically much harder to use and more flexible.  Firebase is pretty easy to use, plus they just integrated messaging.  (In the past you'd often have to use it in conjunction with PubNub.)  (PubNub is awesome of course.)

Comment: Yeah, but the question is, does the Firebase Unity SDK work on Windows and OSX platforms? It looks like its just for mobile.

Comment: Right, I want to know the answer too.  Great question.

Comment: Joe Blow I have decided to go with AWS, it either SDK actually supports desktop and mobile for Unity3D

Comment: Firebase has been updated to provide the majority of functionality within the editor. Setup steps are located here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/start#configuring_the_sdk_for_the_unity_editor